# C#: How to receive a double pointer to struct from a C++ unmanaged function callback

Tags: c#, pointers, callback, pinvoke, marshalling

I will be laconic.
I have a library written in C++ using the openCV lib.
One of my functions is:

```
EXTERN_HEADER HWND createHandle(FListener fl);
```

where FListener is a callback function pointer defined as:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *FListener)
(int fSN, int fC, byte* fSData, IplImage **fS);
```

IplImage is an openCV struct.

I am trying to use this library and these functions in C# so i am DllImport-ing as such:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
delegate void FListener(int fSN, int fC, ref byte fSData, ref IntPtr fS);

[DllImport("FLib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, 
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int createHandle(FListener fl);
```

and finally i declare the method that will be called back to my c# program as:

```
private void test(int fSN, int fC, ref byte fSD, ref IntPtr fS)
{
    //how -for the love of God- do I access that openCV double pointer struct 
    //inside "fS"?
}
```

Naturally fS is a pointer to an array of pointers pointing to IplImages.
Do I have to declare the IplImage struct again inside my C# code?
I dont want to use any C# wrapper for openCV. I want to keep things "clean" and "simple"
but i am totally stuck with the marshalling part... Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: If i pass the fS array as an IntPtr* it works like a charm. The elements are retrieved as fS[0], fS[1] etc. If I pass it as a "ref IntPtr" then the first element can be retrieved as fS but where can i find the second one e.t.c.? I tried fS + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IplImage)) with no luck... any ideas?

No ideas at all?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done Platform Invoke, but I think your callback will have to be unsafe, e.g.,

```
unsafe delegate void FListener(int fSN, int fC, ref byte fSData, IplImage **fS);
```

This may not be the exact syntax, but it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: You can't declare a pointer to a managed type and i was wondering if i could avoid the unsafe stuff... but thank you anyway. :)

Comment: If IplImage is a struct, you certainly can declare a pointer to it.

Comment: I have read so syself too but when compiling i get the following: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type.

Answer (score 0):

As for your second question, you can access the other elements using the IntPtr.ToPointer() method in unsafe code, so that you will have a pointer to the base of the structure/array of pointers or whatever, and then you can simply use the indexer the access them, for example:

```
int* p = (int*)fS.ToPointer();
p[3] = ...;
```

if it's a pointer to array of IntPtrs do the same, ToPointer once again.

Comment: Thank you for that. If i assume the expected fS to be an IntPtr (and not as a ref IntPtr) then your example works ok. Is there any way i can avoid the unsafe block? Thank you again.